# How to pivot a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

[image]

And I want result like this

[image]

I tried pivoting but could not get this result. Because there can be more than four values in first table.

NOTE:
this is question is quite different from the mentioned above by some one. The answer in the similar question shows another result set, while I have attached images to avoid such stupid confusion.

Comment: There are no mind-readers here. So if you want to be pointed to the errors you've made in your query - you have to show your query first.

Comment: Hmm, can you provide more details on what is your table structure and how you want to pivot that ?

Comment: The above images speaks clearly about the structure of the table. And the second table also indicates what result I want.

Comment: have you tried this?:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx
Or do you not know all the "Title" values you have if your original table?

Comment: @Alex_404, in the given link, pivot query mentions columns explicitly like "FOR DaysToManufacture IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])", In my case 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 can be dynamic. Means number of columns can vary.

Comment: Calling a duplicate flag "stupid confusion" is not likely to ingratiate you to other people who might want to help. Think about it: If you take the principles shown in the other answer, and just remove one column from what it's doing, that will answer your question.

Comment: Downgrading to some one question and flagging question as duplicate, merely without check what I want in my answer is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, this is a duplicate of dynamic pivot question. However, I just did something like this few days ago and still have the query.

Replace < table > with your table name:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''
SELECT @sql = @sql+SUBSTRING(t.cols, 0,LEN(t.cols))
FROM (SELECT stuff((SELECT DISTINCT '['+a.Title+'],'
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Title FROM <table>) a
                FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'') AS cols
        ) AS t
SET @sql = 'SELECT '+@sql+CHAR(10)+
          +' FROM (SELECT Title,Value'+CHAR(10)+
          +'       FROM <table>) AS src'+CHAR(10)+
          +' PIVOT'+CHAR(10)+
          +' (max(Value) FOR Title IN ('+@sql+')) AS pvt'
exec(@sql)
```